# Cannot edit embedded info.plist within JRE that's causing CFBundleIdentifier Collision

Tags: java, macos, libgdx, app-store, mac-app-store

I'm trying to upload an app to the mac app store and keep getting

```
CFBundleIdentifier Collision - The Info.plist CFBundleIdentifier value 'net.java.openjdk.cmd' of 'java' is already in use by another application.
CFBundleIdentifier Collision - The Info.plist CFBundleIdentifier value 'net.java.openjdk.cmd' of 'pack200' is already in use by another application.
```

I'm embedding a JRE within my app and these two files require unique bundle identifiers.

How do I change the Info.plist within java/pack200 if it's embedded within the executable? Changing it with a text editor just corrupts the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.

What I was doing wrong was editing java/pack200 with a text editor. I ended up using a hex editor and edited the bundle identifier value of "net.java.openjdk.cmd" to a unique bundle identifier before packing it.

The new bundle identifier must be the same length of characters as the old one or else it won't be available to codesign.

Comment: @J W which hex editor did you use? I'm trying to edit the java and keytool executables with vim. However, once I do that, the executables no longer work. For instance, I tried to change net.java.openjdk.cmd to net.java.openjdk.cm1 and I get ❯ java --version
[1]    35665 killed     java --version

Also, what java version are you using for embedding the mac app? Appreciate the help.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: If I do this, I get an error when trying to code sign:
`main executable failed strict validation
[ERROR]     In subcomponent: [..]/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java`